# Trajectory of vector field$ v = (x^2 -1, xy)$

Tags: calculus, integration

> I have been tasked with finding the trajectory of the vector field $v = (x^2 -1, xy)$

---

My solution yields $x^2 - y^2 / c = 1$

However, the textbook answer gives $x^2 +- y^2 / c^2 = 1$.

I cannot figure out why it is plus or minus $y^2$

Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: The solution uses $c^{2}$ instead of $c$. Your $c$ can be positive or negative.